# Git log --pretty=oneline appears to omit first 2 commits

Tags: macos, git

This might be a bug but I've never seen a bug in Git before, and I can't find any mention of this issue on the intertubes, so for now I'll assume user stupidity.

I use Git a great deal so I've set up an alias to bring up a birds-eye view of the git log: `alias gl='git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit'`. So when I'm juggling between different branches, I'll frequently type `gl` to pull up the log, then `q` to exit. I find this super convenient.

But today I've noticed something strange: it looks like the most recent two commits are excluded from this view. Here's sample output from `gl` for one of my active projects:

```
b6e802d Location autocomplete; major refactoring and cleanup
d0cecdf Admin can download CSV of all users
0149ea2 Changed some verbiage on terms, privacy and profile page
5c0bdff Changed the link for find coach to go to the coaches page
```

But if I output gl to a file like `gl > gitlog.txt`, the first few lines are:

```
5e57f97 City autocomplete supported in mobile navbar search
df43a02 Add firstname & lastname to admin's users CSV download
b6e802d Location autocomplete; major refactoring and cleanup
d0cecdf Admin can download CSV of all users
0149ea2 Changed some verbiage on terms, privacy and profile page
5c0bdff Changed the link for find coach to go to the coaches page
```

Note that the top 2 lines in the latter are not present in the former.

If I open up the normal `git log`, all commits are visible as expected.

**EDIT**: I just discovered that I can work around this for now by piping (redundantly, I think) to less: `gl | less` shows all commits as expected.

I never noticed this happening before now (ie. the past couple weeks); I've recently updated to a newer Git version, could that be related? Has anyone else seen this happen? What should I do to figure out what's going on here? I don't even know where to start. Does this look like a bug?

Numbers:

- Mac OSX 10.9.5
- Git 2.2.1
- Are any other numbers relevant?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer, but I just made a couple observations:

- This is only happening with one particular repository. The git log works fine on other projects.
- I've added several more commits in the last day or two, and all of those commits are excluded. So it's not that *the latest 2 commits* are hidden so much as that *every commit after a certain one* are being excluded.

The earliest commit being hidden begins with the following line:

```
Add firstname & lastname to admin's users CSV download
```

Given the behavior of the error, I think there's a bug with Git's log printout that causes some commits to be hidden if a commit message contains `&`. So the lesson for me, for now, is to not use `&` in Git commit messages.

Answer (score 1):

Just reproduced this behaviour happening with an old git version (2.6.x), but I updated it (2.19.1) and it was then fixed.